# What could cause code coverage enabled builds to fail?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-coverage, xcode8, xcodebuild

### Summary

I'm trying to get a code coverage report from my project. However when I try to build and run tests, there is no CodeCoverage folder created in the derived data folder.

### How am I trying to do this?

I am running xcodebuild as follows:

`xcodebuild \
-workspace <some_workspace> \
-scheme <some_scheme> \
-destination <some_destination> \
-derivedDataPath <some_path> \
-enableCodeCoverage YES \
build test`

### What is the problem?

For my workspace/project it fails at the very end with a line:

`xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace <some_workspace> with scheme <some_scheme>.
    Reason: Could not determine bundle identifier for <some_test_target>'s TEST_HOST: "<some_path>/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<some_product>.app"`

At first it seemed directly linked to the TEST_HOST issue, but that's not the case here.

*There is simply no CodeCoverage folder:*

`<some_path>/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage`

### What have I tried?

I tried the same with a clean new project, same running the same `xcodebuild` command, which succeeds. Within the `Build/Intermediates/` folder exists the `CodeCoverage` folder.

However, in my own project, which is more complex, the `Build/Intermediates/` folder contains a bunch of `*.build` folders (related to the app and the various frameworks, `HockeySDK.build` for example) and `PrecompiledHeaders` but no `CodeCoverage` folder.

When looking through the output of `xcodebuild` I never see a reference to the `CodeCoverage` folder for my project. However, for the test project, the first mention is at:

`Write auxiliary files`
`/bin/mkdir -p /<some_path>/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/Intermediates/<some_project>.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/<some_project>.build/Objects-normal/x86_64`

For my project I see:

`Write auxiliary files`
`/bin/mkdir -p /<some_path>/Build/Intermediates/<some_project>.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/<some_project>.build/Objects-normal/x86_64`

### Workaround

Something else that seemed to 'trick' it into working is to set the `Host Application` to `None`. After doing this it builds and tests, but tests fail due to the lack of host. However, this causes the `CodeCoverage` folder to be created, and if the `Host Application` is correctly set again, running the build and tests works fine, with a code coverage report produced.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that it's something to do with your test target scheme. You are running the tests though command line but what does it do if you run the tests through Xcode (make sure code coverage is turned on for the scheme)?

Comment: I get the same error message "Could not determine bundle identifier for..." certainly seems like a project set up issue, which could well be the problem. Interestingly if I uncheck `Gather coverage data` it builds and runs the tests fine.

Comment: Please post <some_path>/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<some_product>.app/info.plist

Comment: Here is the info.plist: http://pastebin.com/raw/9HbtzUxc

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39655865/1457385

Comment: Thanks @shallowThought that was it. The debug product name was named slightly differently, in fact it had a "-" in the name, which was replaced with "_" during the build, I renamed the product name so it's consistent across all schemes/configurations and now it seems to be fine. If you answer this question, even if it's to point to the other question, I'd like to send the bounty to you.

Comment: Nice. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assure the package name is equal in all configurations. Xcode modifies it in case you are using unsupported characters. For instance Xcode replaces "-" with "_".

In all configurations, go to:

`Project` -> `Build Settings` -> `Product Module`

and set the exact same name without spaces.